# Reach host's folders from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

I have a folder in host machine's this directory `/files/username/`. `username` is variable.

And this is my Dockerfile's CMD directive:

```
CMD ./entrypoint.sh
```

I want to get contents of `/files/username/` folder in `entrypoint.sh`. And I can get username variable as an environmental variable like this:

```
$ docker run -e username="User 1" ...
```

In this way is it possible to reach host device's folders inside `entrypoint.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

**Share the main folder**

```
docker run -v /files:/files -e username="User 1"
```

This way your entrypoint script will be able to work on any user

**Share only user folder**

```
docker run -v /files/user:/files/user -e username="User 1"
```

This would only give access for that particular user

Comment: Creating volumes is a good idea and will solve my problem. But I have a question. I need to isolate docker container from host's file system. So is there any other option?